# Div not closing when clicked outside the div?

Tags: jquery

Why is the div not closing/hiding when clicked outside the div. I am using following javascript to close/hide the div when clicked outside the div.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = new Array();
    container.push($('#openModal'));

    $.each(container, function(key, value) {
        if (!$(value).is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && $(value).has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            $(value).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Markup of div I want to close is following.

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/84419229?autoplay=0" width="854" height="480" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("body").children().not("#openModal").on("click",function() {
  $("#openModal").hide();
});
```

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").children().not("#openModal").on("click",function() {
    if(!$('#openModal').is(':visible')) $("#openModal").hide();
  });
});
```

Though you have already a `$(document).ready()` section in your code. You can place it inside there too

Comment: it didn't work. You can view at snapnsolve.com. The div opens by clicking the 'Watch Video' button in the header.

Comment: While this may provide an answer, can you please provide some commentary as to what it's doing and how it answers the question?

Comment: I checked your site. It does not fire cuz you didnt use it inside `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Could you please give me the full jquery code that I need to put in there? I am sorry I am new to jQuery.

Comment: Still doesn't work. In fact, now the div is not even opening. Please check snapnsolve.com

Comment: @user3455154 my bad. Forgot to check if it's visible. Edited again. Try new one please. This should work

Comment: @Batu Zet I am afraid this didn't work as well. Could you check?

Comment: @user3455154 edited again. Forgot the `!`. Did you try @cepharum 's solution. That one doesnt work either?

Comment: No this is not working as well.  @cepharum 's solution is not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is somewhat odd in that you are pushing a jQuery instance to array (though this instance is something similar to an array itself already) just to iterate over this single-jQuery-instance-array. Additionally, you are recreating this array each time event handling occurs though DOM isn't changing in between, is it?

You might also try something similar to this instead of your code:

```
var modal = $('#openModal > div');
$(document).mouseup(function( e ) {
    if ( !$(e.target).is(modal) ) {
        modal.hide();
    }
} );
```

But trying code on your site directly this was working for me:

```
$("#openModal").on("click",function() {
    if($('#openModal').is(':visible')) $("#openModal").hide();
});
```

It is hiding your `#openModal` though it might not stop playing the video hiddenly. You might reduce it to this eventually:

```
$("#openModal").on("click",function(e) {
    $(e.delegateTarget).hide();
});
```

Putting this in a DOMReady-event handler like this will ensure the elements are available already:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#openModal").on("click",function(e) {
        $(e.delegateTarget).hide();
    }); 
});
```

In addition this is making your code more flexible for not interfering with other libs probably using `$` for shortcut actions.

Comment: None of them worked. The site is at snapnsolve.com. Do yo mind having a look please? The div opens by clicking the 'Watch Video' button in the header.

Comment: I was having a look at your site before writing this answer. BTW the play button `.vidaps` is sometimes covered by other element `.intro` as well. The #openModal was fullscreen, thus I wasn't able to click outside of it. And thus I tried adjusting approach of Batu Zet to exclude single child element of #openModal which isn't fullscreen.

Comment: It worked but partially. Once the div closes, it won't open again if I click the Watch Video button.

Comment: There seem to be more oddities in your site's logics to fix ... as I pointed out above already the play button is covered unless you're maximizing your browser window on a landscape orientation screen. The code above is just hiding some DOM elements on clicking, it isn't handling any additional state management.

Comment: Please help me, what do I do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51194/discussion-between-cepharum-and-user3455154)